# Forestplot - multiple variables and dataframes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using following code to do forestplot.

It works well with no problems, but I would like to plot forestplot from two dataframes. So that the result would either have variables from each dataframe under each other, or at the same line with different colour.

Also ggplot changes the order of my variables to Z -> A, and I would like them to stay in an un-alphabetical order.

```
forestplot <- function(d, xlab="Estimate", ylab="Study"){
  require(ggplot2)
 p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, ymin=ylo, ymax=yhi)) + 
geom_pointrange() + 
coord_flip() +
geom_hline(yintercept=0, lty=3) +
ylab(xlab) +
xlab(ylab) + #switch because of the coord_flip() above
ggtitle("...")
return(p)
}    
forestplot(d)
```

Result would be something like this (without crappy editing and with multiple varialbes):

[image]

Comment: This is possible in the forestplot package

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the two data frames at the beginning of your function:

```
 forestplot <- function(d1, d2, xlab="Estimate", ylab="Study")
   {
   d = rbind(cbind(d1, df = "1"), cbind(d2, df = "2"))
   require(ggplot2)
   p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, ymin=ylo, ymax=yhi, color = df, group = df)) + 
   geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
   coord_flip() +
   geom_hline(yintercept=0, lty=3) +
   ylab(xlab) +
   xlab(ylab) + #switch because of the coord_flip() above
   ggtitle("...")
   return(p)
 }
```

[image]

```
 set.seed(1)
 d1 <- data.frame(y = runif(5), 
             x = sample(c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5"), replace=F))
 d1$ylo = d1$y - runif(1)
 d1$yhi = d1$y + runif(1)

 d2 <- data.frame(y = runif(5), 
             x = sample(c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5"), replace=F))
 d2$ylo = d2$y - runif(1)
 d2$yhi = d2$y + runif(1)

 forestplot(d1,d2)
```

**EDIT**

```
 print(d1)
           y  x          ylo       yhi
 1 0.2655087 s5  0.059534088 0.4420654
 2 0.3721239 s4  0.166149325 0.5486807
 3 0.5728534 s2  0.366878788 0.7494101
 4 0.9082078 s3  0.702233215 1.0847645
 5 0.2016819 s1 -0.004292644 0.3782387

 print(d2)
           y  x         ylo       yhi
 1 0.6870228 s5  0.03534908 0.8125779
 2 0.3841037 s2 -0.26757005 0.5096588
 3 0.7698414 s3  0.11816765 0.8953965
 4 0.4976992 s4 -0.15397452 0.6232543
 5 0.7176185 s1  0.06594474 0.8431736
```

I can not reproduce your error (comment) with this data, the problem might be in the input data frames.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot!

Comment: Infact i still have an problem..
The script you gave me works, but the estimates arent right, it draw the to incorrect  values, for example:
In dataframe 1:  CRP11 = mean 0.06406516 ylo 0.012618338 yhi 0.11551199
dataframe 2 : CRP11 = mean -0.010406175  ylo -0.0634425313 yhi 0.04263018

Comment: ....
In dataframe 1 (gray) :  CRP11 = mean 0.06406516 ylo 0.012618338 yhi 0.11551199

dataframe 2 (yellow) : CRP11 = mean -0.010406175  ylo -0.0634425313 yhi 0.04263018

Still the result looks like this: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvlksh8fac649lo/Screenshot%202016-06-08%2011.02.34.png?dl=0
The values aren't at their place?
@bVa

Comment: I just edited my answer. The values are not at their place with your data, I checked with the data used in the answer, and here it works. I could not reproduce your error. Maybe check and correct the variable names (`y = mean` ?) in the function.

Comment: Yep, i got it right now, had an error in my code, which messed the result. Sorry for bothering, Thanks!